Summation of Amplitude with Many Soft Photons in Peskin and Schroeder
In Peskin and Schroeder QFT section 6.5, they try to show the cancellation of infra-red divergence in amplitude with soft photons of all order.
Following Weinberg's approach, they show that by considering following cases, we can prove the cancellation of infra-red divergence.

First consider the soft photons are connected to the outgoing charged-particle

We represent the shaded part of the diagram as $i\mathcal{M}_{\text{hard}}$, in this case, suppose there is no additional soft photon on incoming particle, we have,
$$\bar{u}(p')i\mathcal{M}_{\text{hard}}\left(p'+\sum{k_i}, p\right)u(p)\left(e\frac{p'^{\mu_{1}}}{p'\cdot k_1}\right)\left(e\frac{p'^{\mu_{2}}}{p'\cdot k_2}\right)\dots\tag{6.76}$$
Then consider the soft photons are connected to the incoming charge-particle,

then we should have, if in this case there is no additional photons on outgoing particle,
$$\bar{u}(p')i\mathcal{M}_{\text{hard}}\left(p', p-\sum{k_i}\right)u(p)\left(-e\frac{p^{\mu_1}}{p\cdot k_1}\right)\left(-e\frac{p^{\mu_2}}{p\cdot k_2}\right)\cdots$$
Apparently, the shaded amplitude $i\mathcal{M}$ is different in two extreme case, however, in eq(6.77), they add all possible connections of soft photons on either incoming particle or outgoing particle, and extract the shaded amplitude $i\mathcal{M}$, which confuses me a lot, why can the shaded amplitude be extracted out?
Moreover, in the following step,in eq(6.78), they combine 2 soft photons to form a virtual photon loop and integrate over photon momentum $k$, which again ignores $i\mathcal{M}_{\text{hard}}$ dependence on $k$, why we can ignore it?


In the following we will only discuss real and virtual photons with momentum $k$ attached to the 2 external legs with momentum $p$ and $p^{\prime}$.

OP asks about the effects of the $k$-dependence inside the hard part ${\cal M}_{\rm hard}$ of the amplitude. The main answer is that the Refs. 1-3 are assuming that the real photons are soft $|k^0|<E_{\ell}$ and also that the virtual photons are soft with (after Wick rotation) $k_E^2<E_{\ell}^2$, so that we may ignore the $k$-dependence in ${\cal M}_{\rm hard}$.

The main point of Ref. 1 is that the IR regulator $\mu$ drops out of the final formula (6.84), i.e. there is no net IR divergences: The IR divergences of the soft real photons precisely cancel the IR divergences of the virtual photons to all orders in perturbation theory.

What about hard virtual photons $k_E^2>E_{\ell}^2$? One may argue that for a single virtual photon [see e.g. eq. (2.23) in Ref. 3] that there is a natural UV cut-off of order ${\cal O}(\frac{q^2_E}{k_E^4})$ for $q:=p^{\prime}-p$, so no UV divergence. [Eq. (2.23) can presumably be iterated to more virtual photons.]
Alternatively, if ${\cal M}_{\rm hard}$ is 1PI, the $k$-loop must go through at least 1 propagator inside ${\cal M}_{\rm hard}$, which implies [by counting superficial degree of (UV) divergence] that there is no UV divergence caused by the virtual photons.
But there are finite contributions unaccounted for, which is presumably what OP is really asking about.


References:

M.E. Peskin & D.V. Schroeder, An Intro to QFT, 1995; section 6.5 top of p. 203.

S. Weinberg, Phys. Rev. 140 (1965) B516; beginning of section II.3.

D.R Yennie, S.C Frautschi & H. Suura, Ann. Phys. 13 (1961) 379, eq. (2.23).


